# How to change or add style property onClick event

Tags: jquery, css, styles, height, addition

I have a menu that when its open at the mobile version, it does not close when clicking on a link, so I would enter a height:2px in a div style to close the menu.

I'm trying to do the following, but is not working:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html"><span></span>Link 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html"><span></span>Link 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html"><span></span>Link 03</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
 $('.navbar-collapse collapse').on('click', function(){
document.getElementById("teste").style.height = "2px";
});
</script>
```

Comment: By clicking a link the page scrolls or refreshes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (but correct jquery selector for navbar as shown below)

```
<script>
 $('.navbar-collapse.collapse').on('click', function(){
    $("#teste").css('height','2px');
});
</script>
```

You can give multiple css prorties at once like below

```
<script>
     $('.navbar-collapse.collapse').on('click', function(){
        $("#teste").css({height : '2px',
      backgroundColor : "#ddd",
      fontWeight: ""
      });
    });
    </script>
```

[JQuery CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect.

Use

```
$('.navbar-collapse.collapse').on('click', function(){
```

instead of

```
$('.navbar-collapse collapse').on('click', function(){
```

As you are using multiple classes just write the selectors together without spaces in between